# why minimum_should_match does not return multiple match?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i am refering to this question
[How to use "OR" in Dev Tool Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522942/how-to-use-or-in-dev-tool-query)
While trying to extend this to 3 Match with a minimum should match number to 2 it does not return any when i set it like this  ""minimum_should_match":1" its works, but only gives 1 match, but when i do like this ""minimum_should_match":2"  then it does not return anything, where as i know the query should found minimum 2 match which are in the log

so what i am doing wrong ?

```
    GET _search 
   { 
   "query":{ 
      "bool":{ 
         "must":[ 
            { 
               "match":{ 
                  "log.file.path":"mylog.log"
               }
            },
            { 
               "term":{ 
                  "GPS-LOG.IMEI":{ 
                     "value":"1234567"
                  }
               }
            },
            { 
               "bool":{ 
                  "should":[ 
                     { 
                        "term":{ 
                           "GPS-LOG.COMMAND":{ 
                              "value":"HB"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                      term":{ 
                           "GPS-LOG.COMMAND":{ 
                              "value":"DB"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     { 
                        "term":{ 
                           "GPS-LOG.COMMAND":{ 
                              "value":"TR"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match":1
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":{ 
            "range":{ 
               "@timestamp":{ 
                  "gte":"now-10m"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: May you please tell what do you expect from parameter `minimum_should_match`? Do you mean that there should be at least N documents matching the terms of the query, or that in each matching document there should be at least N matching terms?

Comment: Hi, if i do a normal grep on that log file , i.e grep DB|TR|HB, it return all the  lines which matches with those keyworkd, 
for the same rules , its only returning lines which matches only one keyword , 
I need to return matches for minimum 2 key word, hope it make sene

Comment: Thanks for replying. The `should` part looks good to me (should do what you need). So I would assume that the problem is in the different part of the query, or in the ingestion of the documents itself. Please check that the `must` part above isn't too restrictive (try to remove it and see what happens). Also I would recommend to try to take a closer look and check that the data in the logs and in the index is exactly the same (querying for stuff that was lost will result in not finding anything, I mean).

Comment: Also take a look at the `filter` part since it reduces the documents by timestamp.

Comment: Hi Thanks
the filter time is fine, i have checked in that time , logs with those Keyword are present, 
I also change from must to should but still same...

Comment: Can you find an example document in the index (that should be returned by the query but isn't) and add it to your question?